# Interpolate Terraform local variable from resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a default bucket policy if none is provided by `terraform.tfvars` via the `var.override_policy` variable.

In my below configuration I am attempting to use `"${aws_s3_bucket.destination.arn}"` in my local block and then use the computed local as my bucket policy.  When I change this interpolation to a variable or hardcode it, I am able to get Terraform to plan successfully.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "destination" {
  provider = "aws.dest"
  count    = "${var.bucket_side == "dest" ? 1 : 0}"  
  acl      = "private"
  bucket   = "${var.dest_bucket_name}"

  website {
    index_document = "index.html"
    error_document = "error.html"
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.dest_bucket_name}"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "destination" {
  provider = "aws.dest"
  count    = "${var.bucket_side == "dest" ? 1 : 0}"
  bucket   = "${aws_s3_bucket.destination.id}"
  policy   = "${var.override_policy != "" ? var.override_policy : "${local.default_bucket_policy}"}"
}

locals {
  default_bucket_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "${var.dest_bucket_name}-policy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowRead",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:List*",
        "s3:Get*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "${aws_s3_bucket.destination.arn}",
        "${aws_s3_bucket.destination.arn}/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

When I try to plan the above version though, I get the following error.

```
Error: Error running plan: 1 error occurred:
        * local.default_bucket_policy: local.default_bucket_policy: Resource 'aws_s3_bucket.dest
ination' not found for variable 'aws_s3_bucket.destination.arn'
```

Is there something I am missing or is attempting to use interpolation inside of a local just a limitation of Terraform?

Comment: If you can upgrade to Terraform 0.12 this should fix itself as it introduces lazy evaluation of conditional statements.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't update to tf 0.12 for this project yet :(

Comment: I'd happily accept a "you can't do this in tf 0.11" if there's something in the docs or a good answer somewhere else you can point me at.